# Cantidad y no repetidos en ArrayList Android

Tags: android, arraylist

Hola tengo un arraylist con el objeto `prePedido`. el cual esta compuesto con su ID, un IDcliente, un IDproducto y un idRestaurant.

Lo que necesito es armar otro array sin que se repita el IDproducto. Y si se repite solo guardarlo 1 vez y contar cuantas veces se repite. Es decir si me array tiene 2 productos iguales, con el mismo IDproducto, en un array guardar solo 1 vez y contar cuantas veces esta repetido es decir si esta repetido 1 vez me mostraría un 2. Acá mi código en un Onresponse recorriendolo para pasarlo a un adapter.

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("prePedido");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<json.length();i++){
            prePedido PrePedido = new prePedido();
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
            PrePedido.setNombre_producto(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
            PrePedido.setPrecio(jsonObject.optDouble("precio"));
            PrePedido.setIdCliente(jsonObject.optInt("idCliente"));
            PrePedido.setIdProducto(jsonObject.optInt("idProducto"));
            PrePedido.setIdRestaurant(jsonObject.optInt("idRestaurant"));
            PrePedido.setId(jsonObject.optInt("idPrePedido"));
            precio = jsonObject.optDouble("precio")+precio;
            pedidos.add(PrePedido);
        }
        adapter = new PrePedidoAdapter(this, pedidos, usuario);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        total.setText("El total es: $"+String.valueOf(precio)+'0');

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: hola juampi, podes utilizar un Set para evitar duplicados en tu ArrayList, para contar duplicados haces un for del array y te fijas con contain si existe

Comment: Me podrías explicar un poquito mejor? Gracias

Comment: @Juampi creo que sería lo ideal en lugar de crear otro ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar esto:

> Lo que necesito es armar otro array sin que se repita el IDproducto.

primeramente declara otro ArrayList donde serán almacenados los elementos no repetidos:

```
List<prePedido> pedidosNoRepetidos = new ArrayList<>();
```

y puedes insertar elementos a este array asegurando no existen el elemento en caso de existir determina no agregarlo, esto lo puedes agregar después de agregar el elemento a el ArrayList `pedidos`:

```
   ...
   ...
                pedidos.add(PrePedido);

                boolean repetido = false;
                for(int j=0; j<pedidosNoRepetidos.size();j++){
                    if(pedidosNoRepetidos.get(j).getIdproducto() == PrePedido.getIdproducto()){
                        //Se encuentra actualmente en ArrayList el elemento.
                        repetido = true;
                        break; //Si encuentra un elemento repetido deja de buscar en el ArrayList.
                    }
                }
                if(!repetido){ //Agrega si el elemento no se encuentra repetido en el ArrayList
                    pedidosNoRepetidos.add(PrePedido); //Agrega en Arraylist de elementos no repetidos
                }

            }
```

---

**Para indicar los elementos repetidos** puedes agregar a tu objeto `prePedido`  la propiedad `cantidad` :

```
   private int cantidad = 0;

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
```

Ahora cuando encuentre que el elemento ya se contiene sumara 1 a la propiedad:

```
        ...
        ...
        for(int j=0; j<pedidosNoRepetidos.size();j++){
            if(pedidosNoRepetidos.get(j).getIdproducto() == PrePedido.getIdproducto()){
                //Se encuentra actualmente en ArrayList el elemento.


                pedidos.get(j).setCantidad(pedidos.get(j).getCantidad() + 1);

                repetido = true;
                break; //Si encuentra un elemento repetido deja de buscar en el ArrayList.
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
```

Puedes usar la propiedad getCantidad() para obtener el número de veces que se encuentra repetido el elemento.

Al terminar el `for` puedes usar este otro `for` para imprimir la información:

```
    for(prePedido p : pedidos){
        Log.i(TAG, "Elemento: " + p.getIdproducto() +" repetido: " + p.getCantidad() + " veces.");
    }
```

Comment: Ahora si señor.! Muchas gracias